# Missing axis in uiaxes - matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I used app designer to build an image viewer GUI. When I load an image to app.UIAxes the axis ticks disappear. Any idea how to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: Add `axis('on');`

Option 2: Check the 'Axes visible' option in the Image Processing Toolbox Preferences

[image]